# Powershell Script to install trusted publisher certificates

Tags: powershell, certificate, pki

I use powershell app deployment tool kit and I have a script to install a few MSI's. For one of the MSI's, I have a certificate (`cert.cer`) that I need to install on each machine's trusted publisher.

After doing some digging, I came up with this:

`certutil.exe -addstore TrustedPublisher cert.cer`
`certutil.exe -addstore root cert.cer`

This does not work, no errors, I am just still being prompted to have to accept an install from a non trusted publisher.

Answer (score 8):

Open PowerShell as administrator and run:

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath cert.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher
```

Comment: This also adds all certificates in the chain to TrustedPublishers, that is bad. Therefore all certificates from the same root ca are considered to be TrustedPublisher.

Comment: @K.Frank Interesting. I had not considered a scenario that included multiple certificates in the `.cer` file. I know that is possible with some certificate formats. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: No, I just have a publicly trusted .cer file that I tried to import. And Import-Certificate than also adds the CAs that signed the certificate as Trusted Publishers

Comment: ... was a cat file not a cer file. When first extracting the cer file it works as it should. So the error is in special handling of cat files. Therefore attention when using this command for installing drivers, as there you have cat files

Comment: @K.Frank That is doubly interesting. What kind of certificate was it that got added? A root certificate, intermediate/chain, or driver signing certificate?

Comment: This is the iso image that contains the driver, if you'd like to take a look: https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/archive-virtio/virtio-win-0.1.173-9/virtio-win.iso
The file I used is: `amd64/2k19/viostor.cat`
In oder to install the msi in the root silently right afterwards

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look later tonight or tomorrow and update if I find anything interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the above problem that import-certificate imports all the certificates in the chain I prefer `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` which should read .cer files, too.
Then you can access the signer certificate and add it to the store.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/61533687/1133043
$CertFile = get-item <path to .cer file>

$CertStore = Get-Item "cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher"
$CertStore.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite)

$Cert = (Get-AuthenticodeSignature $CertFile.FullName).SignerCertificate

Write-Host ( "Added {0}, {1} from {2}" -f $Cert.Thumbprint, $Cert.Subject, $CertFile.FullName )

$CertStore.Add($Cert)
$CertStore.Close()
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me,

```
$pfx = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 
$certPath = read-host "Certificate Path"
$pfxPass = read-host "Password" -assecurestring
$pfx.import($certPath,$pfxPass,"Exportable,PersistKeySet") 
$store = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(
    [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::TrustedPublisher,
    "localmachine"
)
$store.open("MaxAllowed") 
$store.add($pfx) 
$store.close()
```

Comment: This question is for a non-PFX certificate. Though, there is a similar `Import-PfxCertificate` cmdlet that would allow you to make a less complicated import script.